# Python loop through long list for matching strings and concatenate

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation, match

I am trying to loop through a list in order to find filenames that match except for the final character and concatenate the matches into one string.

The difficulty I have is that there are varying amounts of matches per filename, so there could be a single file with no matches, a file with two matches, three or four.

I am using the 'skip' variable in order to try and move through iterations of the loop that have already been matched to avoid duplicates.

I think the problem arises from me using the 'i' variable to get the element from the list possibly but I am unsure.

As you can probably tell I am new to Python and programming and have a serious flaw somewhere in my logic that I can't see! If anything is unclear I will explain as best I can and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
reader = [34113751IHF.jpg, 34113751IHR.jpg, 34136676OTD.jpg, 34136676OTF.jpg, jpg34136676OTR.jpg, 34136676OTF.jpg, 34136676OTR.jpg, 34139933EDD.jpg, 34139933EDF.jpg, 34144626KXF.jpg, 34144626KXR.jpg]

iterable = iter(reader)

skip = 0

for i, j in enumerate(iterable):

    firstURL = str(j)[2:-2]
    firstShorter = str(reader[i+1])[2:-3]
    secondURL = str(reader[i+1])[2:-2]
    secondShorter = str(reader[i+1])[2:-3]

    if firstShorter == secondShorter:
        toWrite = firstURL + ".jpg|" + secondURL + ".jpg"
        thirdURL = str(reader[i+2])[2:-2]
        thirdShorter = str(reader[i+2])[2:-3]
        skip = 2

        if secondShorter == thirdShorter:
            toWrite += "|" + thirdURL + ".jpg"
            fourthURL = str(reader[i+3])[2:-2]
            fourthShorter = str(reader[i+3])[2:-3]
            skip = 3

            if thirdShorter == fourthShorter:
                toWrite += "|" + thirdURL + ".jpg"
                fifthURL = str(reader[i+4])[2:-2]
                fifthShorter = str(reader[i+4])[2:-3]
                skip = 4

    else:
        toWrite = firstURL + ".jpg"
        skip = 1

    [iterable.__next__() for x in range(skip)]
```

Comment: Can you please write what output you expect? It's very hard to understand your problem. Do you want a list like so: ["34113751IHF34113751IHR", "34136676OTD34136676OTF", ... ]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a group all filenames that match (except the last character and '.jpg') into a string that's all the filenames concatenated? Here's an example how to do that:

```
from collections import Counter

# The list you provided
reader = ['34113751IHF.jpg', '34113751IHR.jpg', '34136676OTD.jpg', '34136676OTF.jpg', '34136676OTR.jpg',
          '34136676OTF.jpg', '34136676OTR.jpg', '34139933EDD.jpg', '34139933EDF.jpg', '34144626KXF.jpg',
          '34144626KXR.jpg']

# Creating a copy of the list but without the last character and '.jpg'
check_list = [x[:-5] for x in reader]

counter = Counter(check_list)
grouped_list = [[k]*v for k, v in counter.items()]
```

This will create a list of all the filenames that match your criteria. If you want a string representation of that list you can do this:

```
string_rep = " | ".join(["".join(element) for element in grouped_list])
print(string_rep)
OUTPUT: 34113751IH34113751IH | 34144626KX34144626KX | 34139933ED34139933ED | 34136676OT34136676OT34136676OT34136676OT34136676OT
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Saved me hours of scratching my head!